# Database recommendation storing a growing set of recordings

Tags: nosql, database-recommendation

Suppose I have a large volume of recordings coming in from various sources. Encoded as JSON-lines, they might look like this:

```json
{ "metric": "temperatureRange", "values": [ "new-york", "2023-02-06T11:42:09", "18.1", "24.6" ] }
{ "metric": "windSpeed", "values": [ "tokyo", "2023-01-06T09:21:30", "7.1" ] }
{ "metric": "humidity", "values": [ "london", "2023-01-06T09:21:30", "0.65" ] }
{ "metric": "windSpeed", "values": [ "london", "2023-02-04T12:54:55", "5.6" ] }
```

The data is non-relational (in the sense of no foreign keys) and I only ever want to append data. Recordings are never modified after writing. Notice that the `values` list is not of a fixed size. That said, I think I could choose a reasonable upper-bound of—say—16 values.

In terms of querying, I want to be able to do look-ups like:

- Find all rows where the metric is `windSpeed`
- Find all rows where the metric is `humidity` and first value is `"new-york"`
- Find all rows where metric is `temperatureRange` and the second value is `"24.6"`

I can model this in a traditional RDBMS, however I don't think that is optimized for this use-case. This is because I anticipate a high volume of writes but only very simple queries.

**What is a good database system for this type of work load?**

Comment: What makes you think a relational database would not be optimized for this ? Do you have any hard constraints in terms of query response time ? Or data ingestion throughput ? Or data volume ? How much data are we talking about ? How many concurrent accesses ?

Comment: Almost any database would work, unless you come up with some extreme requirements such as number of rows or response time.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind I have tweaked the question a little

Answer (score 0):

> The data is non-relational...

I see `Cities` that relate to different weather metrics, such as `TemperatureLogs`, `WindSpeedLogs`, and `HumidityLogs`. So the data is pretty relational actually. These weather metrics tables would be Foreign Key-able on `City` (or `CityId` ideally in a normalized database) to the `Cities` table.

> In terms of querying, I want to be able to do look-ups like:
>
> - Find all rows where the metric is `windSpeed`
> - Find all rows where the metric is `humidity` and first value is `"new-york"`
> - Find all rows where metric is `temperatureRange` and the second value is `"24.6"`

These kinds of questions are typically most efficiently answered by querying a normalized relational database, such as with the aforementioned tables I stated.

> I can model this in a traditional RDBMS, however I don't think that is optimized for this use-case.

It absolutely is, if you're willing to do the work of creating a normalized database. See above.

> **What is a good database system for this type of work load?**

Any modern relational database (RDBMS) would work just fine. Stick to something that's mainstream / popular so that there's a lot of information, documentation, and support in the community whenever you have questions. Examples are SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle SQL.

Comment: I mean non-relational in the sense that I do not have any foreign key constraints

Comment: @sdgfsdh You would be able to Foreign Key the example tables I provided in my answer.

Comment: Adding FK constraints would slightly slow down inserts since the FK must be checked.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Sure, so it's up to you if you want to implement them or not. But my point is the data is relational and ergo Foreign Key-able. Also, unless you're inserting 100,000 rows per second, every second, 24 hours a day, 7 days a week, it's unlikely you'd experience any noticeable `INSERT` performance difference.